# Generate all undirected graphs with n nodes

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph-theory

I'm trying to generate all the undirected graphs with n nodes, using recursive backtracking. I have to write their matrix (I don't know how is it called in english - in my language it would be adjacent matrix - is that right?) into a file.

For example:

input

```
3
```

output

```
8
0 0 0 
0 0 0 
0 0 0 

0 0 0 
0 0 1 
0 1 0 

0 0 1 
0 0 0 
1 0 0 

0 0 1 
0 0 1 
1 1 0 

0 1 0 
1 0 0 
0 0 0 

0 1 0 
1 0 1 
0 1 0 

0 1 1 
1 0 0 
1 0 0 

0 1 1 
1 0 1 
1 1 0
```

Here is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

ifstream f("gengraf.in");
ofstream g("gengraf.out");

int st[100], n, adiacenta[100][100], l=1;

void tipar(int k)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < k; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < k; j++)
        {
            adiacenta[i][j] = adiacenta[j][i] = st[l];
        }
        l++;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < k; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < k; j++)
        {
            g << adiacenta[i][j] << " ";
        }
        g << endl;
    }
}

int valid(int k)
{
    return 1;
}

void back(int k)
{
    if (k == ((n - 1) * n / 2) + 1)
    {
        l = 1;
        tipar(k);
        g << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
        {
            st[k] = i;
            if (valid(k))
            {
                back(k + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    f >> n;
    g << pow(2, (n * (n - 1))/2);
    g << endl;
    back(1);
}
```

but my output is:

```
8
0 0 0 
0 0 0 
0 0 0 

0 0 0 
0 0 0 
0 0 0 

0 0 0 
0 0 1 
0 1 0 

0 0 0 
0 0 1 
0 1 0 

0 1 1 
1 0 0 
1 0 0 

0 1 1 
1 0 0 
1 0 0 

0 1 1 
1 0 1 
1 1 0 

0 1 1 
1 0 1 
1 1 0
```

and I don't know how to fix that.

I see why does happen - I generate 2^(n*(n-1))/2) graphs (because that's how many undirected graphs with n nodes are), and instead of generating 8 distinct ones, I get only 4 distinct ones, shown 2 times.

That is (I suppose) because my program outputs a graph with, let's say, a link between the node 1 and 3 and another graph with a link between the node 3 and 1. And that is basically the same undirected graph.

So if I am right, I should make my program not show each graph twice and it should work. So basically I have to get rid of each graph with the "reversed" node (so if I got one with a link between 1 and 3, I shouldn't get another one with a link between 3 and 1 because they are the same).

Am I right?

If so, how can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: The method "valid" always outputs 1. Is there a reason for having it? Because then you don't need that `if()` statement with `back(k + 1);` in it, since the result of walid is always 1 = true;

Comment: This is link a template that I've learnt from one of my teachers. In the valid() function, I should have the conditions which have to be met in order for the solution to be OK. In this case, all variations of nodes are fine, so that is why it always returns 1.

Comment: this is like a template* it should have the conditions* sorry, typo, stackoverflow won't let me edit it though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems with your code:

- Value of `l` in `tipar()` id not increased after assignment.
- Size of adjacency matrix is n * n not k * k.

This code work as expected.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

ifstream f("gengraf.in");
ofstream g("gengraf.out");

int st[100], n, adiacenta[100][100], l=1;

int pow(int a, int b) {
    int r = 1;
    while (b) {
    if (b&1) r *= a;
    b >>= 1;
    a *= a;
    }
    return r;
}

void tipar()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j <= n; j++)
        {
            adiacenta[i][j] = adiacenta[j][i] = st[l];
            l++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        {
            g << adiacenta[i][j] << " ";
        }
        g << endl;
    }
}

int valid(int k)
{
    return 1;
}

void back(int k)
{
    if (k == (n * (n-1) / 2) + 1)
    {
        l = 1;
        tipar();
        g << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
        {
            st[k] = i;
            if (valid(k))
            {
                back(k+1);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    cin >> n;
    g << pow(2, (n * (n - 1))/2);
    g << endl;
    back(1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had to change the cin to f, but indeed it worked as expected. Great answer!